# Woocommerce 3.2.6 jQuery Not Loading After Update

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently running Wordpress 4.9.1

My Woocommerce has been updated to the latest version (3.2.6), and now my website is broken. All images fail to load, buttons don't work.

I can see the problem in my Console is that jQuery is no longer loading.

[image]

If I look at the page source, I can see that the URL to the jQuery CDN has a 'defer' attrubute, and the URL is missing the 'HTTPS:'.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js' defer='defer'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>try{jQuery.noConflict();}catch(e){};</script>
```

What could be causing the jQuery to fail here?

Comment: Your script tags that include jquery should be at the top of your page - you have inline javascripts on your page that call jQuery functions triggered before the jquery is included. Put it in your <head> tag.